# TypeError: Cannot read property 'Symbol(dartx._get)' of null (in Flutter when adding Firestore Listener)

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am unable to add a listener to my firestore document. I am getting the above error which I am not understanding as to what is causing it. My code is as follows:

```
 StreamSubscription<DocumentSnapshot> listener;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_){
      _initListener();
    });
  }

  _initListener() async {
    listener = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('Ref to my collection path')
        .doc('status')
        .snapshots()
        .listen((DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
            Map<String, dynamic> firestoreInfo = documentSnapshot.data();
            setState(() {
              paid = firestoreInfo['status'];
            });
            if(paid) Navigator.pop(context);
          });
      listener.onError((handleError){
      if(DEBUG) print('Cannot attach listener: Error: $handleError');
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    listener.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

EDIT: MY BUILD METHOD IS AS FOLLOWS:
I am using a web view plugin to display a payment page. My intention is to read data on firebase and see when it is updated and then move to payment success or payment failure page.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        iconTheme: IconThemeData(
          color: Colors.white, //change your color here
        ),
        elevation: 0.0,
        title: Text("PAYMENT", style: Header),
        backgroundColor: Provider.of<CP>(context, listen: false).primary,
      ),
      backgroundColor: Color(0xfff6f7f8),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(13.0),
            child: Text('Please enter your payment details'),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
              child: EasyWebView(
                onLoaded: (){},
                src: 'PATH FOR PAYMENT URL',
                isHtml: false, // Use Html syntax
                isMarkdown: false, // Use markdown syntax
                convertToWidgets: false, // Try to convert to flutter widgets
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(13.0),
            child: Text('Your payment info is encrypted and protected by STRIPE', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12, fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Post your `build` method or the whole page

Comment: @dm_tr added build method

Answer (score 1):

Your issue I think is here:

```
.listen((DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
            Map<String, dynamic> firestoreInfo = documentSnapshot.data();
            setState(() {
              paid = firestoreInfo['status'];
            });
            if(paid) Navigator.pop(context); // issue
          });
```

You notice paid isn't initialized outside of the `setState` just inside it so your if statement doesn't have accuss to `paid`. Change it to this:

```
.listen((DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
            Map<String, dynamic> firestoreInfo = documentSnapshot.data();
            setState(() {
              paid = firestoreInfo['status'];
            });
            if(firestoreInfo['status']) Navigator.pop(context);
        });
```

Comment below if you have any questions or if this didn't solve your issue

Comment: @Damandriod did this solve your question? If so please upvote and mark as accepted.

Comment: your answer gave me a starting point. I have upvoted it.

Comment: awesome, glad to help

Answer (score 0):

So, the issue was that `paid = firestoreInfo['status'];` was returning null. One I put the null checks in place, the error went away. paid variable is initialised globally to false.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not writing this answer for this particular question but for anyone getting this `TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'Symbol(dartx.***)')` error while using Firebase and Flutter. I wasn't able to get field or to reach any doc or collection and the only thing came up was this error.

Everything was in place except ONE LITTLE THING:

Firebase console > Firestore Database > Rules > line 5: from `allow read, write: if false;` to  `allow read, write: if true;`

I was trying to reach the data without the user login, so the only thing that must be changed was this. I hope this helps someone one day.